# Why isn't the U-2 used for commercial purposes?

Tags: reconnaissance-aircraft, lockheed-u2

There are some companies that use decommissioned military aircraft for commercial high-altitude flights (for, say, tourists). Examples would be the MiG-31 and the MiG-29:

Why isn't the [Lockheed U-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_U-2) used for such flights? Here is a two-seat version of the U-2:

[image]

( [Image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_U-2#/media/File:Lockheed_U-2_TR-1B.jpg) )

Is the U-2 still secret? Or is it expensive to build?

Comment: it's nearly entirely titanium... also what commercial purposes would you envision?

Comment: It would cost more than likely anyone is likely to pay.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Titanium? Aren't you confusing it with that other Skunk Works reconnaissance plane?

Comment: Excellent! Thank your for sourcing your image.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is expensive to operate, and there is no economic value in what it does.

Apart from reconnaissance and espionage, the U-2 is used for high-altitude atmospheric research, but since it is operated by NASA and man-carrying, it is subject to an immense bureaucracy. When you want to fly your own scientific instrument on it, you need to go through years of certification procedures. The instruments which are rated to fly on the U-2 are ancient and much less precise than what can be built today. Therefore, most high altitude research is done by balloons, where the bureaucracy is much less suffocating.

Comment: I meant something like taking tourists to the edge of space.

Comment: @user3624251: Except for the view and the custom-fit suit, there is not much spaceflight feeling in operating the U-2. No weightlessness, no fiery reentry, but much boredom.

Comment: @user3624251 It was used for a "tourist" at least once - Adam Savage of Mythbusters got to take a [joy ride on a U2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters_(2015_season)#Episode_230_.E2.80.93_.22Flights_of_Fantasy.22).

Comment: @T.J.L. I'm aware of two instances of people riding shotgun in a U-2 for television: [James May  for a BBC special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_May_at_the_Edge_of_Space) and Adam Savage, for an episode of Mythbusters.

Comment: @ThomasOwens James May, too, huh? I'm not surprised. I'll have to try to dig that up.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with "instruments which are rated to fly on the U-2 are ancient and much less precise than what can be built today". I don't know what payloads NASA flies on their U-2, but the USAF payloads are quite modern. In fact, their payloads are still being upgraded on a regular basis. Some are more incremental, but they are by no means ancient. From what I've seen, it's much easier to get new payloads and technology onto a government or military aircraft than a commercial aircraft, in terms of certification. Just from what I see on a day-to-day basis.

Comment: Here it is, James May in U-2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIJRoj2qwsc

Comment: @ThomasOwens The first unmanned aircraft I worked on in my career was on purpose designed to put modern instruments into the stratosphere inside the southern polar vortex. Those instruments would not be touched by NASA, but they proposed man-rated, ancient, heavy instruments of lower precision. The U-2 would had operated out of Punto Arenas, making each flight expensive and limiting the top altitude. Think about it: The researchers would rather build a new aircraft than accepting the rotten deal NASA was offering.

Comment: "Suffocating"... really? You had to use that word when talking about high-altitude work? :)

Answer (score 6):

Because the owners of the U-2s (the USAF and NASA) don't make them available for commercial use. Presumably, the U-2s on display in Norway and the UK and the US aren't operable and were supplied on the condition that they wouldn't be operated.